# build_exectuable in julia-0.45, linux, julia.h error

Tags: linux, julia

There are problms with build_exectuable:
  on linux ubuntu 16.04 LTS
the command build_executable did not work (julia version 0.4.5)

The command

```
build_executable("test","/media/ophir74/unix/rdf_files/rdf/main_exp_pdf.jl","/media/ophir74/unix/rdf_files/rdf/target","native",force=true)
```

showed the error message

> /tmp/tmpqG1ttJ/start_func.c:1:19: fatal error: julia.h: No such file
>   or directory compilation terminated.

the julia.h is in a different folder (/julia/src/)
yet the file that call julia.h (start_func.c)
looked for that in the same folder (/tmp/tmpqG1ttJ)

that's just about the accurate path
*** how to solve the problem??

the full message

> running: gcc -g `` -I/usr/include/julia -I/src -I/src/support
>   -I/usr/include /tmp/tmpqG1ttJ/start_func.c -o /usr/bin/test -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/julia -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/julia -ljulia -ltest
>
> /tmp/tmpqG1ttJ/start_func.c:1:19: fatal error: julia.h: No such file
>   or directory compilation terminated.
>
> ERROR: failed process: Process(setenv(`gcc -g -I/usr/include/julia
>   -I/src -I/src/support -I/usr/include /tmp/tmpqG1ttJ/start_func.c -o /usr/bin/test -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/julia
>   -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/julia/julia -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/julia -ljulia -ltest`,Union{ASCIIString,UTF8String}["LC_PAPER=he_IL.UTF-8","LC_ADDRESS=he_IL.UTF-8","LC_MONETARY=he_IL.UTF-8","SHELL=/bin/bash","TERM=xterm-256color","LC_NUMERIC=he_IL.UTF-8","USER=root","LC_TELEPHONE=he_IL.UTF-8","LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:","SUDO_USER=ophir74","SUDO_UID=1000","USERNAME=root","MAIL=/var/mail/root","PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin","LC_IDENTIFICATION=he_IL.UTF-8","PWD=/home/ophir74","LANG=en_US.UTF-8","LC_MEASUREMENT=he_IL.UTF-8","SHLVL=1","SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/bash","HOME=/home/ophir74","LANGUAGE=en_US","LOGNAME=root","LESSOPEN=|
>   /usr/bin/lesspipe
>   %s","SUDO_GID=1000","DISPLAY=:0","LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s
>   %s","LC_TIME=he_IL.UTF-8","XAUTHORITY=/home/ophir74/.Xauthority","LC_NAME=he_IL.UTF-8","_=/usr/bin/julia","OPENBLAS_MAIN_FREE=1"]),
>   ProcessExited(1)) [1]  in build_executable at
>   /home/ophir74/.julia/v0.4/BuildExecutable/src/BuildExecutable.jl:143

Comment: julia 0.4.5 is not maintained anymore so you might not get much help there. Perhaps also might be good to explain what you end-goal is.

Comment: thenks, the commnad in julia 0.6 also did not work
 There, also the problem is with the paths 
There the error is a bit different
The issue just appeared with build-exectuable, where other packages worked (Roots, NLopt, etc)

The error
"running: /media/ophir74/unix/julia/julia_2040/bin/julia /home/ophir74/.julia/v0.6/BuildExecutable/src/build_sysimg.jl /media/ophir74/unix/julia/julia_2040/lib/libtest native /tmp/tmpTZ3Z1b/userimg.jl --force
ERROR: LoadError: 
UndefVarError: @unix_only not defined
Stacktrace:

Comment: Binary compilation of Julia is currently *experimental*, and is by no means guaranteed to be stable even in v1.0 - see the discussion [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/list-of-most-desired-features-for-julia-v1-x/4481). This means that users should not expect binary compilation to "just work" (yet). If you aren't comfortable diving into the package source to work on errors like this (and submit PR's for any fixes you implement), then you might be better off waiting until this feature is official.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
it was problem of permissions that got messier.
and it was problem that in ubuntu the julia version doesn't upgrade through the regular command:
   "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade julia"
and that build_executable   work just on recent  julia versions

The solution
(1) uninstall ubuntu
(2) re install ubutu
(3) download julia from the website , rather than through the terminal (that presented just the 0.4.5 julia version and doesn't upgrade)
(4) open terminal in the folder of the extracted julia,
enter the full path of the folder and then continue to the "bin/julia" and press enter to work with the 0.6.0 version
(5) Pkg.add("BuildExectuable")

Just what i tried from the list with many 
(that misght help others, the valubale issues were)
(1) Pkg.checkout("BuildExecutable") showed that there is problem with paths
(2) Pkg.free("BuildExecutable") Pkg.rm("BuildExecutable") did progress a bit the issue showing that the problem is with the version of Julia
(3) after various steps the disk showed full.  all the clean commands including fsck -P in recovery mode after boot did not work, and I unistall ubuntu

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu it is strongly recommended you get Julia via binary blobs on the [Julia downloads page](https://julialang.org/downloads/), especially if you want to use experimental features like binary compilation. The repositories all lag the latest versions, some by a factor of years. FYI for other readers I'd be surprised if steps 1 and 2 above, i.e. re-installing Ubuntu, were necessary. It is steps 3 and 4 that fixed the issue.

Comment: what happened is a bit more complicated. it is issue with "root" permissions. when working with Julia through Atom the permissions are not the root permissions.   build_executable was blocked automatically (yet other commands e.g., NLopt worked). When trying to solve this problem, with ```chmod``` command, the disk (after various tests) showed "full", and all the Pkg.rm() commands did not work.    at that stage, the uninstall was the only option. The description might help those that work with Atom [e..g,   possible solution, to work with build_executable through Julia opened with (3,4)]